# JavaScript заменить значение в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
// Массив со словами 
var words = [
  "программа",
  "оладушек",
  "холодильник",
  "автомобиль"
];

// выбор случайного слова 
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

// создаем итоговый массив 
var answerArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  answerArray += "_ "
};

var remainingLetters = word.length;

// игровой цикл 
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
  // Показываем состояние игры
  alert(answerArray);

  // запрос варианта ответа 
  var guess = prompt("Введите одну бувку или введите 'exit'")
  if (guess === "exit") {
    alert("До свидания!");
    break;
  } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Введите только одну букву")
  } else {
    // обновление состояния игры
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
      if (guess === word[j]) {
        answerArray[j] = guess;
        remainingLetters--
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Вопрос: почему `answerArray[j] = guess` не присвает `answerArray[j]` значение из `guess`?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в блоке кода

```
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  answerArray += "_ "
};
```

В ходе выполнения этого кода, `answerArray` становится строкой и так как строки в javascript неизменяемые `answerArray[j] = guess` не меняет `answerArray`.

Для решения достаточно заменить `+= "_ "` на `answerArray.push("_")`. Метод [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) добавляет элемент в массив.

Comment: Недостаточно. :) Надо еще и `alert(alert(answerArray))` заменить на `alert(answerArray.join(' '))`, а то некрасиво будет. :)

Comment: @Yaant, это на любителя :-)

Comment: Ну, из кода в вопросе можно предположить, что автора вполне устраивает разделение символов пробелами, поэтому лучше не менять, вдруг это окажется каким-нибудь гендерным предпочтением. :)